Equivalent of Oracle's empty_blob() in H2
I have a plain Java app (no Spring Boot or anything like that) that uses Oracle, but I need to migrate it to use an embedded H2 instance instead (so it can be deployed on a dev server without the need for Oracle to be stood up).  I've got H2 set in Oracle compatibility mode and Iv'e got it ALMOST all the way there, but I'm stuck on a BLOB issue.
Simply put, the application code creates a record in a table:
insert into my_table (my_field) values (empty_blob())
Then, it executes this query:
select my_field from my_table
Then, it calls setBytes() on the BLOB (java.sql.Blob object) returned by this query and then does:
update my_table set my_field=? where id=123
? here is, of course, the bytes for the data inserted via prepared statement.
Now, let's set aside why it's doing it this multi-phase way... it's an older app, and changing the code isn't really an option... but regardless, in Oracle, this works perfectly.  In H2 though, no matter what I try, I seem to always get the Blob object being null, hence a NullPointerException occurs when calling setBytes().
I've tried several things in the insert statement to get a non-null value:
CAST('' AS BLOB)
BLOB ''
X''
RAXTOHEX('')
''

I also explicitly tried setting a value of null, which I knew wouldn't work, but just stating it for completeness.
In all cases, I still hit the NPE.  I can't seem to insert an empty BLOB in H2 like I can in Oracle, which is the crux of the problem.
Well, not ALL cases: it turns out that doing X'' DOES get me an empty BLOB, but then on the update query, I get an error "Feature not supported: allocate a new object to set its value [50100-224]"... which seems closer, but now I'm not sure how to solve that without changing the code.  So maybe my original question isn't the right one anyway (note that I added this paragraph after the original post when I realized X'' wasn't behaving like the rest, and I THINK the same is true for RAWTOHEX() as well).
Anyone have any ideas what else I could try?  Thanks!

Well, I didn't find a direct, outright answer to my question, but I DID find a solution.
Simply put, although I didn't want to touch the application code, I wound up doing a simple change anyway.
First, for the insert statement, I insert null for the BLOB.  Then, in the code that directly precedes the update query, where it originally was:
final Blob b = rs.getBlob(1);
...I instead now do...
Blob b = null;
if (runningInDev) {
  b = conn.createBlob();
} else {
  b = rs.getBlob(1);
}

That does the trick for H2, still works for Oracle fine as well, and it's a small enough change that I can live with it.
I'd still love to hear if anyone has a way to do it that DOESN'T require that change, but that gets me over the hump with a minimum of fuss, so I'm good to go for now.  Thanks!
